# Prometheus rate limiting

Tags: prometheus

How to deal with the possible explosion of metrics/cardinality metrics so that it doesn't kill the stack. I was thinking of using some rate limiting. Take the value of the scraped metrics at a certain time, add 20%/30% for safety and that would be the value when Prometheus would start ratelimiting the scraped stuff, but how to do that? How do you guys deal with this?

Comment: Because Prometheus pulls metrics from targets, you have control over how many targets the server scrapes, how frequently it scrapes (`scrape_interval`) and, there's now experimental `*_limit` properties too (see [Configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/))